# The count value is not recognized in terraform

Tags: azure, for-loop, count, terraform, cloud

I have a terraform code which has to execute multiple times which means terraform init,plan,apply will be within a for loop. One resource block has a count variable which gets evaluated based on local variable. First iteration works well until terraform apply. In the second iteration it fails at terraform plan with the following error.

```
The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the count depends on.
```

The following block is where count is used

```
resource "null_resource" "test" {
  count = length(local.stacc)
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${local.data[count.index]} >> myfile.txt"
  }
}
```

This **local.stcacc** is achieved based on certain for loop processing which will result in a list. Hence count of items in the list is the value of local.stacc
My doubt is how the first iteration passes but second iteration fails.

Comment: It won't be possible to answer this without seeing how `local.stacc` is defined. Since that's a local value, that'd include also the definitions of anything the local value refers to. The local value seems to be derived from one or more resource attributes, and so this behavior depends on how those resource types are implemented.

Comment: @Marcin The issue is still not received. Is it possible to reframe the above nullresource block using for_each instead of count. I am clueless on how to do it

Comment: Sadly you can't. All variables used in count and for_each must be know in advanced. As I explained, you have to refactor your entire code so that `local.stacc` is known, or use `-target`.

Answer (score 1):

`local.stacc` can't be dependent on other resources. Its value must be know at `apply` time, not during. As the error suggest, use [-target](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/resource-targeting?in=terraform/state) to `apply` and create the resources which are needed for evaluation of `local.stacc`, and then `apply` again to run your `null_resource" "test"`.

Comment: How did it work in the first iteration then? It fails only during the second time it reaches terraform plan